# How does cookiecutter django create database in docker container/image

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, cookiecutter-django

How does running `docker-compose -f local.yml up` create the postgres database in the postgres container with configurations in `.envs/.local/.postgres`. I have looked through the Dockerfiles and cannot seem to find a command such as `createdb` except in the `maintenance/restore` file.

Cookiecutter-django:
https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cookie cutter sets the environment variables which are then read by the Docker image. See Section ***How to extend this image > Environment Variables*** in the official docs: https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I cant believe I missed that the docker images could have environment variables as arguments for default actions